# change the order of the items in the columns

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have this image: [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS9nP.png)
but I'd like to change it like this. [final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii9up.png)
How do I do it? I'm working with recyclerView

My code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    //Boton Atrás
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){ getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    //codigo de lista
    lista2ParaNotas = findViewById(R.id.lista2);
    lista2ParaNotas.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
          false));

    //lista2ParaNotas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    lista2ParaNotas.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    //ArrayList<PuntoNota> puntoNotaList = (ArrayList<PuntoNota>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");
    listaFinal = (ArrayList<PuntoNota>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");

    AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(this, listaFinal);
    lista2ParaNotas.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

I have this image: original image but I'd like to change it like this. final image How do I do it? I'm working with recyclerView.
my code AdapterDatos

```
public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolderDatos>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<PuntoNota> puntoNotaList;

public AdapterDatos(Context context, ArrayList<PuntoNota> puntoNotaList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.puntoNotaList = puntoNotaList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    ViewHolderDatos viewHolder = new ViewHolderDatos(itemView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {

    holder.punto.setText(puntoNotaList.get(position).getPunto());
    holder.nota.setText(puntoNotaList.get(position).getNota());


    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return puntoNotaList.size();
}

public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView punto, nota;

    public ViewHolderDatos(View item) {
        super(item);
        punto = item.findViewById(R.id.idPunto);
        nota = item.findViewById(R.id.idNota);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: help me please.

Comment: Could you post code for AdapterDatos?

Comment: I just sent my adapterData

Answer (score 2):

Please sort your collection before going to the adapter.

```
listaFinal = (ArrayList<PuntoNota>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista"); 

Collections.sort(listaFinal , new Comparator<PuntoNota>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(PuntoNota o1, PuntoNota o2) {
                return o1.getNumber().compareTo(o2.getNumber());
            }
        });

AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(this, listaFinal);
lista2ParaNotas.setAdapter(adapter)
```

And also replace the `getNumber()` with your custom class field.

Comment: ordering does not work correctly. The image looks just like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS9nP.png but I want it this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii9up.png

Comment: Ok if you want to align like that, Then you have to edit your ArrayList before setting to the adapter. i.e you have to **split your ArrayList** into two **ArrayLists**, 
 `for(int i=0;i<listaFinal.size();i++){ 
    if(i%2 == 0)
     list1.add(listaFinal.get(i));
   else
      list1.add(listaFinal.get(i));
  }
 listaFinal.cear();
 listaFinal.addAll(list1);
 listaFinal.addAd=ll(list2);
`